# How to find titles containing a string using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

For example how can I find Wikimedia Commons categories containing the string "shape" in title, using SPARQL?

Also I would like to ask how to change the script in order to:

- make the search case insensitive
- search whole words instead of string
- search articles instead of categories
- search Wikipedia elements instead of Wikimedia commons elements

Comment: SPARQL functions `contains` or `regex` are the way to go.

Comment: @AKSW thanks. I have no idea how to build such a simple query though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic version, using `regex` to filter the results to those containing "shape". For the further **String** functionalities you need (points 1 and 2), you should have a look here on [SPARQL String functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strings).

Your points 3 and 4 are not clear for me, and I suggest posting a dedicated other question for them.

```
select distinct ?catName where {
    ?s wdt:P373 ?catName. # Name of the Wikimedia Commons category for ?s
    Filter (regex (?catName,"shape")) # basic filtering of the results to those containg "shape"
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I just could not find the time to test it. I tried it now and I get 60 results. While in the same time [this tool](https://tools.wmflabs.org/grep/index.php?lang=commons&project=wikimedia&namespace=14&pattern=shape) returns 1506 results. Do you know why there's such a difference?

Comment: Maybe the script can only find the categories that are linked in WikiData?